# odsfile not found (MiKTex)

Tags: luatex, miktex, odsfile

I've installed `odsfile` via MiKTeX, but I can't use odsfile. I tried updating MiKTeX, but I'm still getting the error`Package: xparse 2023-01-16 L3 Experimental document command parser)[\directlua]:1: module 'odsfile' not found:`. What is the issue?
`
MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{odsfile}

\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}
```

Complete error message

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (MiKTeX 23.1) (format=lualatex 2023.3.26)  26 MAR 2023 20:43
 restricted system commands enabled.
**foo.tex
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-10-03.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/f
ontloader-2022-10-03.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.120
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'. L3 programm
ing layer <2023-02-22>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'.
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/odsfile/odsfile.sty
Package: odsfile 2022/12/13 v0.7 odsfile package to select cells from ODS sheet
s and typeset them as LaTeX tables

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
Package: luacode 2012/01/23 v1.2a lua-in-tex helpers (mpg)

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.
sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestac
k.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count191
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable12
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable13
)
\luacode@lines=\toks16
\luacode@table@soft=\catcodetable14
)
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count192
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xpars
e.sty
(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-02-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-lua
tex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package: xparse 2023-01-16 L3 Experimental document command parser
)[\directlua]:1: module 'odsfile' not found:
    no field package.preload['odsfile']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'odsfile'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.75 \end{luacode*}

                  
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

[\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'templates')
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.217 \tabletemplate{empty}{-{content}}
                                     
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

[\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'templates')
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.219 ...{default}{-{colheading}-{rowsep}-{content}}
                                                  
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

[\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'templates')
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.229 }
     
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

) (./foo.aux)
\openout1 = foo.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 7
.

(C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2022/07/10 v2.5l Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

[1

{C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (./foo.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1133 strings out of 478287
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:23,3:4,4:1,5:23,6:2,7:50,9:18
 21315 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 72i,5n,73p,173b,123s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<//?/c:/users/user/appdata/local/programs/miktex/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmrom
an10-regular.otf>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 3775 bytes).

PDF statistics: 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: your example runs without error in texlive 2023

Comment: odsfile.lua is /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/odsfile/odsfile.lua it should have been installed in a similar location in miktex

Comment: I manually copied it to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\odsfile\odsfile.lua` and ran `texhash`. This seems to work. Probably a packaging issue.

Comment: `odsfile` is in miktex ([here](https://miktex.org/packages/odsfile) it is on miktex's website) and your example works fine for me with miktex

Comment: @mbert this is strange. https://miktex.org/packages/odsfile/files shows that `odsfile.lua` is missing.

Comment: @someonr Yes this has recently been [reported](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/366) to miktex